# Most efficent way to save custom settings

Tags: vb.net, settings

My VS2013 VB app currently saves settings to the Registry and it has grown to the point this is bothering me. So I want to save the settings (strings) to files. A bonus is they can then be on the network and used by multiple users. There may be hundreds, even thousands of lines. What is the preferred format to use? The old INI, CSV, XML? The Settings files don't appear to be a good option in this case so far as I can see.

Comment: *Settings files don't appear to be a good option in this case*  why?

Comment: Not knowing what the full extent of what will be saved is, and they are on the local system, not the network.

Comment: I dont know what that first part means.  There is not a clear description of the problem to solve, but... a) INI files have been obsolete since 2003 at least.  b) Using the *system* registry for *user* settings has been a bad idea for about as long. c) Settings can be set to Local or Roaming for a long time now d) You can also use a custom settings provider so you can still use the IDE UI but do whatever you want with them.  As a last resort there is stuff like the answer you accepted

Comment: Plutonix, thanks for your help. I agree about the INI files and Registry, I was just listing options, even poor ones. I will look into the roaming settings. Forgive my ignorance, however if I don't know how may settings will be saved (depends on how much they choose to change from my defaults), can I at runtime create Settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly recommend creating object of a class and use serialization to XML for .NET applications. It is easy to implement, fully supported and you can import and export settings from one computer to another. you can even set your application to ready the settings from network. In addition, It will make future programming / upgrades easier.

I am listing here a working example ( Tested ). The code is in use since 2012 and working perfectly for an enterprise level application.

Note: I only included one " setting item " for demo so you add your own.

**First : Settings or Options Class :**

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports System.IO

<Serializable()> _
Public Class Options

    Public KEYS_USE_LISTS As Boolean

    Public Sub New() 
        KEYS_USE_LISTS = True 
    End Sub

#Region "Methods"

    Public Sub Save(ByVal Path As String)
        Try
            Dim _XMLSerilizer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Options))
            Dim _StreamWriter As New StreamWriter(Path)
            _XMLSerilizer.Serialize(_StreamWriter, Me)
            _StreamWriter.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error saving database setting." & vbCrLf & "Internal Error: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Function DoLoad(ByVal Path As String) As Options
        Dim _Opt As New Options
        Try
            If IO.File.Exists(Path) Then
                Dim _XMLSerilizer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Options))
                Dim _FileStream As New FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open)

                _Opt = DirectCast(_XMLSerilizer.Deserialize(_FileStream), Options)
                _FileStream.Close()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error loading database setting." & vbCrLf & "Internal Error: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
        Return _Opt
    End Function

#End Region


End Class
```

**Second : Use it through interface ( WinForms for example )**

```
Public Class frmOptions



    Public _options As New Options

    Private Sub frmOptions_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        If IO.File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "/_Options.opt") Then
            _options = _options.DoLoad(Application.StartupPath & "/_Options.opt")
        End If

        chkUseList.Checked = _options.KEYS_USE_LISTS 

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnOk_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOk.Click

        If IO.File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "/_Options.opt") Then
            _options = _options.DoLoad(Application.StartupPath & "/_Options.opt")
        End If

        _options.KEYS_USE_LISTS = chkUseList.Checked 
        _options.Save(Application.StartupPath & "/_Options.opt")

        Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
        Me.Close()

    End Sub



End Class
```

Comment: Why are you preceding your variable names with an underscore? That goes against VB.NET's naming conventions (especially `Public` ones!). Also, instead of `Dim _StreamWriter ...` and `Dim _FileStream ...` put them in [**`Using` blocks**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement).

Comment: Valid comment, Thanx!